# Image inside input field no input overflow

Tags: css, image, input, tailwind-css

I have an input field which contains an svg image on the right side of the input field. But actually when i type something into the input field and the input reaches the image, the input overflows my image. Is there any way to prevent the input overflowing my image, so that my input field "stops" a few px before the image? I want to do everything in vue with tailwind.

My code so far:

```
<div
class="flex relative w-500px h-48px group justify-center items-center z-1001 pl-8">
<input
  v-model="input"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Input..."
  class="flex h-48px w-500x px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-600 text-black text-18px flex-none border border-transparent rounded focus:border-gray-400 outline-none"
/>
<span
  class="flex absolute right-0 bg-transparent rounded text-base text-gray-600"
>
  <svg      
    class="fill-current"
    width="24"
    height="24"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    ...
   </svg>
</span>
```

The whole stuff should look like this:

[image]

Comment: You could try adding `padding-right` on the input field equal to width of the SVG, then give the image `position: absolute; right: 0`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your code in full - I guess the only change you'd need to make is adding a `pr-` class to the input field and give it a value close to the width of the SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the padding helper classes.

Docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding

Example: https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/8c4c0334d43267319a0e9bcbc1c0cc12

Add "pr-10" to input (padding-right) and p-2 (padding) to wrapper around SVG.

```
<div
class="flex relative w-500px h-48px group justify-center items-center z-1001 pl-8">
<input
  v-model="input"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Input..."
  class="flex h-48px w-500x px-3 py-3 pr-10 placeholder-gray-600 text-black text-18px flex-none border border-transparent rounded focus:border-gray-400 outline-none"
/>
<span class="flex absolute right-0 bg-transparent rounded text-base text-gray-600 p-2">
<svg class="fill-current" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"</svg>
</span>
```

Comment: Oh this was an easy one... Thank you alot, this worked :) Im pretty sure i had this in a previous point of development... :D

Comment: No worries, you had done most of the work already! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.**

You have to make other structure of the result.
Image can't float absolutely over the input. That need to be relative. So the `Input field` should be single container of two childs (input and image). Good choice is flexbox, like:

```
<div class="input-text / d-flex"> <!-- input style like border, padding,...  -->
  <div class="flex-grow-1"><input ...></div>
  <div class="flex-shrink-1"><svg ...></div>
</div>
```